# Unable to make image responsive using viewport width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a image responsive by using viewport width instead of pixels (vh) but when i resize the page the text also moves along with the image i tried to fix this by changing the font size of the text that's moving from pixels to vh but it did not work.

I have also the following meta tag in the html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

HTML

```html
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div class="kygo">Kygo</div>
        <div class="img"> <img src="maskGroup1.png" alt="Profile Picture"></div>
        <div class="tag">#000</div>
        
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
  }

#top{
    float:bottom;
    background-color:#1A1C1E;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
#bottom{
    position: relative;
    float: top;
    background-color:#2F3136;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
}

.kygo{
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-left: 103px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 20px;
}

.tag{
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-left: 103px;
     color: #A2A4A8;
     font-size: 13px; 
}

img{
    max-width: 11.333vw;
    max-width:  20vw;
    padding-left: 27px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
```

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: `float: bottom` [isn't a thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). I wouldn't use floats anyway. They're a pain.

Comment: Lean flexbox and experience the zen of its perfection. Use floats when floating text around an image or other html element. And nowhere else.

Comment: is that what causing the problem using floats?

Comment: So you want a responsive image but you don't want responsive text? If the text isn't responsive, you'll need the element containing the text to be responsive so that it'll still be visible and positioned relative to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for responsive image use width in %. And made some changes as follows

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

#top{
    background-color:#1A1C1E;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
#bottom{
    position: relative;
    float: top;
    background-color:#2F3136;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
}

.kygo{
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: 700;
     color: white;
     font-size: 20px;
}

.tag{
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: 400;
     color: #A2A4A8;
     font-size: 13px; 
}

.name {
  width:75%;
  padding-left:5px;
}
.img{
  width:25%;
  padding-left:5px;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="top">
       <div class="img"> <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Profile Picture">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <div class="kygo">Kygo</div>
        
            <div class="tag">#000</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float for allowed values to use with `float`.

Comment: Thank you so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in the css. As far as I can see, without knowing the idea behind the layout, this is the css with some cleanup.

Note that the size of the image is unkown so it is not clear to me how to give proper margins and paddings.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
#top {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#1A1C1E;
}
#bottom {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#2F3136;
}
.kygo {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-left: 103px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.img {
    max-width:  20%;
    padding-left: 27px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
.img img {
    /* responsive image */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
}
.tag {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: -40px; /* this will partial overlay the top */
    padding-left: 103px;
    color: #a2a4a8;
    font-size: 13px; 
}
```

```html
<!-- this in your <head> section -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- this in your <body> section -->
<div id="top">
    <div class="kygo">Kygo</div>
    <div class="img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/206/150/100" alt="Profile Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="tag">#000</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Its the same issue the picture moves with the text when i run the snippet